# Bar plot switch colors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure

I have the following code in Matlab, which produces a useful plot for me. Now I'd like to make the plot comparable color wise with another plot. For this reason, some colors should be switched: colors for...

'Pre split total EON' with 'Post split total EON'

'Pre split pure EON' with 'Post split pure EON'

'Pre split total RWE' with 'Post split total RWE'

'Pre split pure RWE' with 'Post split pure RWE'.

That is all, but I do not know how to do it, since the colors are assigned automatically...

```
clear all
close all

values = [4 1 11 2 3; 4 1 5 2 -10];
names = {'Pre split total EON' 'Post split total EON'...
    'Pre split pure EON' 'Post split pure EON' 'Post split Uniper';...
    'Pre split total RWE' 'Post split total RWE'...
    'Pre split pure RWE' 'Post split pure RWE' 'PostSplitInnogy'};
categories = {'EON','RWE'};
figure;
b = bar(values,'FaceColor','flat');
ticksList = b(1).XData+arrayfun(@(x)x.XOffset, b)';
xticks(ticksList(:))
xticklabels([names(1,:)';names(2,:)'])
xtickangle(90)
ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('Position', get(ax1, 'Position'),'Color', 'none');
set(ax2, 'XAxisLocation', 'top','YAxisLocation','Right');
set(ax2, 'XLim', get(ax1, 'XLim'),'YLim', get(ax1, 'YLim'));
set(ax2, 'YTick', []);
xticks(b(1).XData)
xticklabels(categories)
for k = 1:size(values,2) % for fancier colors.
    b(k).CData = k;
end
```

[image]

Comment: _"... the color for names(1) should be switched with names(2) and names(3) with names(4)"_. I mean ... !? Forgive me for not understanding that.

Comment: It should be clear now, see edits.

Comment: _"'Pre split total EON' with 'Post split total EON'"_ . Forgive me for asking again, but just to be clear, you want to switch the colors for those two bars? As in, you want `Pre split total EON` should be `blue`, while `Post split total EON` should be `dark blue/purple`. Right?

Comment: If you're using someone's code, please reference it properly. In this case, the code in your post is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53979735/5698672).

Comment: You can either plot them in the desired order, or specify the individual bar colours manually as described in [this section](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#d120e70420) of the `bar` documentation.

Comment: Using this line: `col = lines(N_names);` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53992040/2627163), you could set the colors manually as you wish.

Comment: Related from same OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071610/bar-plot-with-two-y-axes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like you assigned the colors manually in:

```
for k = 1:size(values,2) % for fancier colors.
    b(k).CData = k;
end
```

if you just want to change the order you can do so by

```
b(1).Cdata = 2;
```

and so on. Alternativly you can change all in one with

```
[b.CData] = deal(2,1,4,3,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know @Finn has already answered this, but when I tested his solution, I couldn't get it to work. Strangely, I realized that even the original script was giving errors on my system. It could be that I have a very ancient version of MATLAB. But then again, I wonder if someone else also has the problem.

For some reason, I cannot set the `CData` member for `bar`.

Anyways, after testing, I got this to work for me.

```
clc
clear all
close all

values = [4 1 11 2 3; 4 1 5 2 -10];
names = {'Pre split total EON' 'Post split total EON'...
    'Pre split pure EON' 'Post split pure EON' 'Post split Uniper';...
    'Pre split total RWE' 'Post split total RWE'...
    'Pre split pure RWE' 'Post split pure RWE' 'PostSplitInnogy'};
categories = {'EON','RWE'};
figure;
b = bar(values,'FaceColor','flat');

% only significant changes here
% ***********************************
col = ["r", "b", "y", "g", "cyan"];
for k = 1:size(values,2) % for fancier colors.
    set(b(k), "FaceColor", col(k));
end
% ***********************************

ticksList = b(1).XData + arrayfun(@(x)x.XOffset, b)';
xticks(ticksList(:))
xticklabels([names(1,:)';names(2,:)'])
xtickangle(90)
ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('Position', get(ax1, 'Position'),'Color', 'none');
set(ax2, 'XAxisLocation', 'top','YAxisLocation','Right');
set(ax2, 'XLim', get(ax1, 'XLim'),'YLim', get(ax1, 'YLim'));
set(ax2, 'YTick', []);
xticks(b(1).XData)
xticklabels(categories)
```

If you want to know more about how are the Colors assigned names in MATLAB, check [here](http://math.loyola.edu/~loberbro/matlab/html/colorsInMatlab.html).

Another thing you can play around is set the `colormap` as explained [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281603/matlab-bar-no-public-property-cdata-exists), the `CData` property is a recent addition, only since `MATLAB R2017b`.